# Regex, посчитать количество чисел 1-3, именно отдельных, а не цифр в строке

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Требуется с помощью Regex посчитать кол-во чисел в диапазоне 1-3 в строке.
Т.е. не количество вхождений цифры в число, а именно отдельных цифр.

Такой вариант подсчитает кол-во вхождений и выведет 7.

```
String s = "52 1 25 37 3 5 74 2 39";
int count = Regex.Matches(s, @"[1-3]").Count;
Console.WriteLine($"{count}"); // Равно 7
```

Необходим вариант регулярки, считающий именно 1 , 3 , 2. int count = 3;

Прошу помочь с составлением регулярки под это условие.

Comment: Так `\b[1-3]\b`?

Comment: `[123]` в данном случае, наверное, более наглядно будет